# How do I route traffic to a specific site/IP-block through one nic, with other traffic through another nic?

Tags: networking, windows-7, routing

I have two NICs:

1. Network 1
2. Network 2

Network 1 is awesomely fast but blocks access to `Site A`. **How can I route traffic to just `Site A` through network 2?**

When I have them both connected, Windows somehow knows to use network 1 for everything (I assume this is via the `metric` setting?).

`Site A` can be an IP address (vs. a domain name) if it makes this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "Route" command.

route ADD (site ip) MASK (site umask) (gateway) IF (number of the interface you want to use)

So to get to 200.200.200.200 on interface 2:

```
route ADD 200.200.200.200 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 METRIC 1 IF 2
```

if you want to make the route change permanent, add the -p flag. The metric doesn't really matter very much in this context, it's more of a statement of priority, so the system knows which route to choose, all other things being equal.

Comment: Presumably that `10.10.10.1` gateway corresponds to whatever IF2's GW actually is?

Comment: @haren: Yes indeed.